# Only top corners rounded in <shape>

Tags: android

I am trying to have the top corners of a shape rounded and the bottom just straight, but I'm having a problem with my shape it's saving

> error!
>   UnsupportedOperationException: null

When I have

```
<corners android:radius="10dp" android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" android:topRightRadius="10dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="10dp" />
```

I have tried putting 1dp in the bottom corners and taking out the android:radius="10dp", but still gives me an error.

Android 2.2 with Eclipse

Can any one help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tool in Eclipse isn't correct, deploy it to a real device and you should see that it is fine.

Comment: Yes this did work I thought it was an error and it wouldn't let me deploy thank you

Comment: Do you know how to bypass the error because now my screen is all grey and cant really see the window properly, this is just in the editor.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by your screen is all grey...?

Comment: The graphical layout screen in eclipse when you preview the app before deployment, the preview screen is shaded to tell you there is an error.

Answer (score 3):

For me it worked fine when i changed 0dip to 0.1dip. Tested on android 1.6

```
<corners android:bottomRightRadius="0.1dp"
         android:bottomLeftRadius="0.1dip"
         android:topLeftRadius="10dip"
         android:topRightRadius="10dip"/>
```

But on the other hand I didn't get any error when I had 0dip. The problem was that all corners was getting 0dip, so it's possible you got another error in the xml

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<corners android:topRightRadius="10dp"
android:topLeftRadius="10dp" />
```